# Is it possible to write code in driver that would limit the output value between zero and one?

Tags: scripting, drivers

I wrote this expression. This is my ternary operator. But I don't know how to complete it using else if.

```
if (location >= 1) else location
```

I want to do this because I need the output value to not be less than zero or more than one. I was hoping this would work, but it doesn't:

```
if(location >= 1 ) else if(location <= 0) else location
```

Is it possible to write code in driver that would limit the output value between zero and one?

Comment: You should probably be looking at something like max(location, x), which returns the highest of the two operands.  min() is similar, returning the lowest.  To limit a value between 0 and 1, you could use max(0, min(1, var))

Comment: Why are using drivers for such simple tasks? Python drivers will be slower than build-in modifiers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do you mean a clamp?

`max(min(location,1),0)`

Thanks to @pyCod3R for their edit.. `clamp(var, minval, maxval)` turns out to be a '[Blender Provided Function](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/drivers/drivers_panel.html#simple-expressions)' for drivers:

The docs for those functions aren't immediately obvious.. so thanks to @Gorgious, too, for finding the relevant chunks of code: [this bit](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/master/source/blender/python/generic/bl_math_py_api.c#L59-L77) reveals a default  0 -> 1 range, when `minval` and `maxval` are not provided.

Comment: FWIW these 3 "provided" functions are defined [there](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/master/source/blender/python/generic/bl_math_py_api.c#L137-L142) and the actual `clamp` driver code is [there](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/master/source/blender/python/generic/bl_math_py_api.c#L59-L77) and the math function is [there](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/master/source/blender/blenlib/BLI_utildefines.h#L348-L357), so the syntax is the one you wrote in your answer. :) I assume just calling `clamp(var)` automagically clamps between 0 and 1

Comment: @Gorgious Cheers! Do you have to have the code loaded in some IDE to find this stuff, or is there another way?

Comment: The method I use is to clone the [blender github](https://github.com/blender/blender)  (which is already a clone of the actual codebase) in visual studio code, then CTRL SHIFT F to find relevant definitions. Then you just have to fetch and pull regularly from VScode source control interface to be up to date. I find it's a pretty straightforward way to dip your toes in the source code :)

Answer (score 5):

The format you are looking for is `location if 0 < location < 1  else 0`

This uses both the ternary form `v1 if condition else v2` and chained tests, since `0 < location < 1` is the same as `location >= 0 and location <= 1`.  You can use the later instead if you find it more readable.

EDIT: as a result of a comment, I see that the actual value should be clamped to either zero or one.  In that case, [*this answer*](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/251691/42221) gives the better form.  You *could* do this with chaining, but Robin Betts' approach is much more readable.

Here is the changed version for completeness `location if 0 < location < 1 else 0 if location < 0 else 1`.  This works because you can use `value1 if condition else value2` in place of `v2` in the original form.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but in your version one thing is missing - if the condition is not met, then we will always have 0. I want the output value = 0 if( location <= 0) and value = 1 if( location >= 1)

Comment: I see.  I didn't get that from your question.  In that case you _do_ want  Robin Betts answer.